# How Can I use Name as res-id instead of index in a MIB table with two key indexes

Tags: mapping, command-line-interface, snmp, mib

[**issue description**]
I have defined a MIB table with two indexes, the table is like this:

```
TerminationEntry OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX TerminationEntry
ACCESS not-accessible
STATUS mandatory
DESCRIPTION
"An entry in the terminationTable ."
INDEX {ifIndex, TkId}
::= {terminationTable 1}
```

And the Tkname and TkId mapping table is：

```
TkMappingEntry::=
    SEQUENCE            
    {
        tkMappingName            OCTET STRING,
        tkMappingId              INTEGER
    }
```

In CLI, I defined two res-id mapping to this two indexes. And for the TkId, the user should input the TkName, and the TkName can be mapped to the TkId. the CLI XML is like this:

```xml
<parameters>
    <res-id uname="if-index" parameter-type="Itf::Line"> 
     <help>The unique internal identifier of the termination port</help>
     <fields>
       <field name="">
         <mib-index name="ifIndex"/>
       </field>
     </fields>
    </res-id>

    <res-id name="tkgname" parameter-type="Sip::TkName">
     <help>The name of Tk.</help>
     <fields>
       <field name="" access="CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringDisplay_c  |
                            CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeWrittenDuringCreate_c">
         <mib-var tree-node="NODEterminationTkName" table-name="terminationTable "/>
         <mib-index name="tkMappingName"/>
       </field>
     </fields>
    </res-id>
<parameters>
...
<fields>
    <field name="index" basic-type="Sip::TkId"
             access="CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringPrepare_c |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringModify_c  |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringCommit_c  |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringDelete_c  |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringIn_c      |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringDisplay_c |
             CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringCreate_c">
        <mib-var tree-node="NODEtkMappingId" table-name="tkMappingTable"/>
        <mib-index name="terminationTkId"/>
    </field>

    <field name="next-free" basic-type="Sip::TrunkGroupId" access="CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringCreate_c">
        <mib-var tree-node="NODE_tkIdNext" table-name="SnmpAgent::localScalarTable_m"/>
        <mib-index name="terminationTkId"/>
    </field>
</fields>
```

But during testing, I find that when I input a unexisted TkName, the next-free field is called and the free index is stored in node tkIdNext. But it is not transferred to the terminationTkId. So my CLI command is failed and I get a error on CLI:referred instance does not exist.

[**note**]
Please help to check the code and help me find why the name/id mapping is failed. By the way, I have tried the name/id mapping in the signle index MIB table, there's no problem. I don't know why the same code can be failed in a two indexes MIB table.

Answer (score 0):

in field name="index", the access "CommandFieldDefinition::mayBeReadDuringCreate_c" should be removed.
During creating node, CLi should only call "next-free" field.